# How to detect a tab in a text file?

Tags: c++, c, file-io

Is detecting tabs same as detecting the spaces? i.e. for detecting a space, I would just compare the space character with its ascii number.

For a tab do I have to search for '\t' character in the file or there is some other way?

Comment: Uhm, tab also has an ascii number: 9

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are working with ASCII data, you can just search for a byte with value '\t' (9) in the text file.  Tabs are represented as a single byte in text files and most libraries for reading files don't do anything special with those bytes.

Comment: @Nick, see my comment to Yew's answer. ISO C does not mandate ASCII as an encoding scheme. However, having said that, the only change that would have to be made to this answer would be the the `9` - everything else would still be correct. EBCDIC also has the wondrous property that `A-Z` are not contiguous, meaning `if ((ch >= 'A') && (ch <= 'Z')) ...` is not that portable, hence things like `isalpha` et al.

Comment: @paxdiablo holy cow -- 'a' to 'z' not contiguous? I suppose this would only be an issue if someone decided to port their code from an ASCII based encoding to something else. And porting is almost never 100% automatic.

Comment: Yep, ISO only mandates the characters provided and the contiguosity (?) of the `0` thru `9` characters.

Answer (score 5):

```
if('\t' == myChar)
```

This would work, and would be better than checking against 9 since 9 may not be a guaranteed value across all architectures.

Comment: Interesting -- do you have such an example of when '\t' is not 9?

Comment: Moreover do you mean to say that standard ascii chart can differ under certain circumstances? If yes, then can you point out which are those?

Comment: I don't know of any actual examples, that's why I said 'may not', but in any case using '\t' will leave it to the compiler to substitute the correct value (9 or otherwise).

Comment: So you are saying it is this just a hunch?

Comment: @Nick, EBCDIC uses 5 for a tab rather than 9 - yes, I know there's not _many_ of these beasts but they're pretty much involved in _every_ piece of money moving around the planet :-)

Comment: Yes, I didn't (thanks @paxdiablo) know for sure but that's not the point; there's simply no reason to use `if(9 == myChar)` because it is both less readable due to the magic number and less portable.

Comment: @paxdiablo -- so there is a C/C++ compiler for EBCDIC operating systems tha translates '\t' to 5 in machine code?

Comment: @Nick, yes. The mainframe beasts have IBM compilers and I think even gcc has a port for it (this is the EBCDIC z/OS UNIX System Services, not the ASCII zLinux stuff).

Answer (score 1):

A tab is just another character so you can check for the ASCII value if you want.

Answer (score 1):

Although a tab appears as 4 or 8 spaces in an editor, it is actually represented as a single character ('\t', like you mentioned) inside a file. Both the space character and the tab character take up one byte. So basically, u are correct in your assumption.